# Make button enabled depending on strings using Combine

Tags: swift, combine

I have a login button named proceed, and have 2 `@Published` properties that represent current typed text in `UITextField`.
What i want is, to assign result of `.filter { !$0.0.isEmpty && !$0.1.isEmpty}` to `Bool` variable `isEnabled` of my `UIButton`

Currently i ended up with this:

```
passwordTxtf.textView.$text
  .combineLatest(loginTxtf.textView.$text)
  .filter { !$0.0.isEmpty && !$0.1.isEmpty}
  .sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] in
          guard let weakSelf = self else { return }
          weakSelf.loginEntered = $0
          weakSelf.passEntered = $1
          weakSelf.setProceedEnableState()
  })
  .store(in: &subscriptions)
```

Where `setProceedEnableState()` is a function that checks class variables and therefore determine button enabled state.

But i want somehow assign that during "pipeline", or do more elegant way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could structure the code such that each of the signals from textview's are assigned to `Subject`s. Here is a small example based on your usecase,

```
let isProcessEnabled = PassthroughSubject<Bool, Never>()
let loginEntered = PassthroughSubject<Bool, Never>()
let passEntered = CurrentValueSubject<Bool, Never>(false)

passwordTxtf.textView.$text.map { !$0.isEmpty }
    .subscribe(passEntered)
    .store(in: &store)

loginTxtf.textView.$text.map { !$0.isEmpty }
    .subscribe(loginEntered)
    .store(in: &store)

Publishers.CombineLatest(passEntered, loginEntered)
    .map { $0 && $1 }
    .subscribe(isProcessEnabled)
    .store(in: &store)
        
isProcessEnabled.sink { isEnabled in
    print("Is processing enabled", isEnabled)
}.store(in: &store)
```

The biggest advantage of this is that you could move `isProcessEnabled`, `loginEntered` and `passEntered`  to your viewmodel or some other object, which would make the whole code more testable. Also, you can see, that you could combine each of these subjects in some interesting way to create some new publisher / subject.

```
class ViewModel {
    
    private var store = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    var isProcessingEnabled: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
        return processEnabled.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    var isLoginEntered: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
        return loginEntered.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    var isPassEntered: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
        return passwordEntered.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    func subscribeLoginText(publisher: AnyPublisher<String, Never>) {
        publisher.map { !$0.isEmpty }.subscribe(loginEntered).store(in: &store)
    }
    
    func subscribePasswordText(publisher: AnyPublisher<String, Never>) {
        publisher.map { !$0.isEmpty }.subscribe(passwordEntered).store(in: &store)
    }

    private var processEnabled = CurrentValueSubject<Bool, Never>(false)
    private var loginEntered = PassthroughSubject<Bool, Never>()
    private var passwordEntered = PassthroughSubject<Bool, Never>()
    
    init() {
        Publishers.CombineLatest(passwordEntered, loginEntered)
            .map { $0 && $1 }
            .subscribe(processEnabled)
            .store(in: &store)
    }
    
}
```

And, you can see that now you have modularized the app and your viewmodel does not need to know specifics of your view / viewcontroller. On the top of that, your code is now, so much testable. You could create an instance of viewmodel and assert your assumptions.

Here is a small sample test case for the above viewmodel implementation,

```swift
class ViewModelTest: XCTestCase {
    
    var store: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    var login = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
    var password = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
    
    var isProcessingEnabled = CurrentValueSubject<Bool, Never>(false)
    var viewModel: ViewModel = ViewModel()
    
    override func setUp() {
        store = []
        viewModel = ViewModel()
        login = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
        password = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
        
        isProcessingEnabled = CurrentValueSubject<Bool, Never>(false)
        viewModel.isProcessingEnabled.subscribe(isProcessingEnabled).store(in: &store)
        
        viewModel.subscribeLoginText(publisher: login.eraseToAnyPublisher())
        viewModel.subscribePasswordText(publisher: password.eraseToAnyPublisher())
    }
    
    func testThatProcessingIsDisabledInitially() {
        XCTAssertFalse(isProcessingEnabled.value, "Processing is enabled")
    }
    
    func testThatProcessingIsDisabledWhenOnlyLoginIsEmpty() {
        login.send("")
        password.send("b")
        XCTAssertFalse(isProcessingEnabled.value, "Processing is enabled")
    }
    
    func testThatProcessingIsDisabledWhenOnlyPasswordIsEmpty() {
        login.send("a")
        password.send("")
        XCTAssertFalse(isProcessingEnabled.value, "Processing is enabled")
        
    }
    
    func testThatProcessingIsEnabledWhenLoginAndPasswordAreNotEmpty() {
        login.send("a")
        password.send("b")
        XCTAssertTrue(isProcessingEnabled.value, "Processing is disabled")
    }
}
```